# Get the sum of details table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve a master record together the sum of its details. Here are the definitions of two tables:

Master table (Master)

```
ID
Name
```

Example record:

```
10 Product
```

Details table (Details)

```
master_id
type (values can only be red or blue)
quantity
```

Example records:

```
10 red 2
10 red 5
10 red 6
10 blue 7
10 blue 9
```

I need to have such results:

```
10 Product 13 (sum for red) 16 (sum for blue)
```

The database is SQL Server 2017. How can I write a SINGLE query without using a stored procedure?

**---UPDATE---**

Based on the input from Venkataraman R, here is the solution:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name ,
SUM(CASE when type='red' then quantity end) as redsum,
SUM(CASE when type='blue' then quantity end) as bluesum
from mydetails as t
inner join mymaster as m
on m.id = t.master_id
GROUP BY m.id, m.name
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "How I can write query"? If you can write stored procedure - you can write query then

Comment: @Fabio, I am able to write simple SQL statements. I understand that with stored procedures you do almost everything. But I just want to have a single statement about the data and am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CONCAT function with group by to get results as single statement.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(master_id int, typev varchar(10), quantity int)
DECLARE @master table(id int, name varchar(50))

insert into @master values(10, 'Product10')

insert into @table values
(10,'red',  2),
(10,'red',  5),
(10,'red',  6),
(10,'blue', 7),
(10,'blue', 9);

SELECT m.name ,
SUM(CASE when typev='red' then quantity end) as redsum,
SUM(CASE when typev='blue' then quantity end) as bluesum
from @table as t
inner join @master as m
on m.id = t.master_id
GROUP BY m.name
```

```
+-----------+--------+---------+
|   name    | redsum | bluesum |
+-----------+--------+---------+
| Product10 |     13 |      16 |
+-----------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks. The master table can contain multiple records with different products. Thus, we can't have fixed "Product". No need for "(sum of red)" or "(sum of blue)". They are just explanation.

Comment: You missed the id column in the master table. I added it and updated the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a group by

```
   Select master_id, type, sum(quantity)
    From details group by master_id, type
```

And use pivot to show each product in one line

```
    With data_cte as 
    (Select master_id, type, sum(quantity)
    From details group by master_id, type)

    Select * from data_cte pivot (
    For type in ('red', 'black'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tested your code. The second statement is not working. Besides, I need a single statement with the results as shown in the post.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly then you are looking for pivot, in that case you can use `case` expressions as following

```
select
    master_id,
    sum(case when type = 'red' then quantity end) as sum_of_red,
    sum(case when type = 'blue' then quantity end) as sum_of_blue
from yourTable
group by
    master_id
```

If you simply wants total quantity by type then use the following

```
select
    master_id,
    type,
    sum(quantity) as total_quantity
from yourTable
group by
    master_id,
    type
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Your first statement is close, but it lacks the name field in the master table. I need a single statement.